# C++ deleting inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

Let's say there is a class *Object* and then another class *Cat* that inherits *Object*. Next, there is a list of *Object** (pointers). Then, I create a new *Cat* and put it into the list. After some time I want to delete all *Cats* and call *delete* on each member of the list. Does it call destructor of *Cat*?

Comment: It seems to me that it would be really simple to write a little test-program and find out yourself.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Actually if he doesn't make base class destructor virtual he will run into undefined behavior which can be rather puzzling in some cases.

Comment: @sharptooth: That is correct. I totally understand that you often want confirmation that a certain piece of code does not invoke UB. But that does not mean that you should not try it first, and then ask that specific question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes if you marked the destructor of object as virtual.

```
class Object {
  public:
  virtual ~Object(){} //make the base class destructor virtual
};

class cat : public Object {
  public:
  virtual ~cat(){} // now this gets called when a pointer to Object that is a cat is destroyed
}
```

Comment: The `Object`-destructor has to be public. Also, the `cat`-destructor does not have to declared as virtual explicitly.

Comment: It does not matter whether `Cat` declares the destructor as virtual or whether it declares it at all, because once a method is declared virtual, it remains virtual in all derived classes. Also declaring it virtual in `Cat` but not in `Object` wouldn't work, because the compiler wouldn't know it should be virtual when calling through `Object*`.

Answer (score 7):

If the destructor of Object is virtual, yes.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is precisely the situation where virtual destructors come in. Read the C++ [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if `class Object` (the base class) destructor is declared virtual, otherwise you run into undefined behavior which you don't want.